# Set the same height to TextViews with different TextSize

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview, text-size

I've tested this with LinearLayout and two TextViews. In both is the same text but with different textSize. I tried to set the height and width in xml and in java and also I tried it with the height 0dp and with weight 1. I don't understand why the second TextView is lower?
How can I set them on the same height?

In a later step I need this in a TableLayout with TextViews and EditTexts and it should be like a crossword puzzle. But after it didn't work there, I've tested it with this simple TestApp.

How it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/in1yL.png

XML File:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView   
            android:background="@drawable/cell_border"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:singleLine = "false"
            >
    </TextView>
    <TextView   
            android:background="@drawable/cell_border"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:singleLine = "false"
            android:textSize="6.5sp" 
            >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Javacode:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView vText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    vText.setText("Dies ist ein Test");
    //vText.setWidth(60);
    //vText.setHeight(60);

    TextView vText2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    vText2.setText("Dies ist ein Test");
    //vText2.setWidth(60);
    //vText2.setHeight(60);
}
```

Thank you for your help in this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
```

in your `<LinearLayout>` . That will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

remove that line : android:textSize="6.5sp"  from second textView on layout. it seems the only different things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally I need a different textSize in the second TextView. My problem is, that the views aren't on the same hight and I don't know why.

Comment: i thing both text view component are same height but the first ones' text size is big. because of that the second text view is lean out.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

The Answer from BaZinga solved the problem.